# Car flasher circuit and grounding

Tags: grounding, automotive

My car flasher circuit can be simplified like so :

[image: Factory flasher diagram]

The factory flasher unit is a standard 2 pin that plugs in series with the switch and the load (indicator lights).

I'm attempting to make my own flasher, and came up with 555 timer outputting a square signal to a mosfet, flashhing the load when the switch is closed.

[image]

My problem here is that I have this ground pin on the 555 timer circuit which essentially makes my flasher unit 3 pins instead of 2 pins. Also in this configuration the flasher is constantly flashing in the background, but not visible until the switch is closed.

How could I make it into a 2 pin system so that only when the switch is closed, the 555 circuit starts flashing ? Can I connect 555 circuit "GND" to the output of the MOSFET through a Diode for example ?

Extra info : the load will be approximatively 5-8 Amps.

Comment: You also need to ensure that on power-on that the lamp turns on instantly not, for example, after one half-cycle of the flasher. At 100 kph you're traveling almost 28 m/s and that half-second delay could be significant in avoiding a collision. The thermal flashers are very clever as they also blink faster when a bulb blows or is disconnected. To do this electronically is a lot more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea.

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [EEV Blog](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/2-pin-flasher-relay-circuit-suggestions/).*

This one uses D1 and C1 to maintain power to the timer circuit  while it is shorted out by the MOSFET.

Be aware of a couple of safety points:

- You also need to ensure that on power-on that the lamp turns on instantly not, for example, after one half-cycle of the flasher. At 100 kph you're traveling almost 28 m/s and that half-second delay could be significant in avoiding a collision.
- The thermal flashers are very clever as they also blink faster when a bulb blows or is disconnected. To do this electronically is a lot more complex. The circuit of Figure 1 won't!
- There is no audible indicator.
- You may have trouble with the dashboard indicator lamps if they rely on a ground connection rather than +12 V.

I recommend the 2-pin electro-mechanical solution. The linked article has some interesting points made by various contributors.